# jQuery: Mouse Interaction + Simple Animation [img]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm new to jQuery so please work with me here. :)

[Site Image] http://imgur.com/zx803Ct

So I'm trying to have the bottles here to animate with cursor interaction.

**Goal:** I want the hovered image to come to the foreground and the rest to shrink into the background.

**Undesired Results:** The code seems to shrink all the bottles without condition. I seem to be running into trouble with the "if, then, else" section.

---

**Process:**

*Store 'mouseEntered' element, do for each bottle, check if match, apply effects.*

**Code:**

```
 $(".sauce_bottle").mouseenter( function(){
        var $active = $(this); //The "entered" image

        //For each (div) bottle, check if "entered", apply effects
        $('.sauce_bottle').each( function(){
            if ( $active == $(this) ) {
            //Shrink
                alert($active.attr("alt"));
                $(this).animate({
                    height: "230px",
                    width: "70px",
                    opacity: ".70"},
                    150);
            } else {
            //or Enlarge
                $(this).animate({
                height: "279px",
                width: "85px",
                opacity: "1"},
                150, function(){});
            }
        });
    });
```

---

If I'm missing a concept (scope) or if you guys have an alternative way of doing this that would be fantastic!

**Thanks guys! :)**

Comment: Can you paste your HTML markup as well?

Comment: <img class="sauce_bottle" src="img/sauce_monkey_venom.png" alt="Monkey Venom" />
    <img class="sauce_bottle" src="img/sauce_sweet_baby_ray.png" alt="Sweet Baby Ray's" />
    <img class="sauce_bottle" src="img/sauce_teriyaki.png" alt="Garlic Teriyaki" /> </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$(".sauce_bottle").mouseenter( function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "279px",
        width: "85px",
        opacity: "1",
    }, 150);

    $(".sauce_bottle").not(this).animate({
        height: "230px",
        width: "70px",
        opacity: ".70",
    }, 150);
});
```

Comment: it's also a good idea to use `.stop()` before the animations so the animation won't continue if you're not hovering it.